# Automatic change value in editbox when is changed in settings

Tags: c#, settings, application-settings

How to change value inside of editbox if is those value changed in settings?

Example: I have two forms, one is main (first) which have editbox and button. Editbox take value from settings and button is used to show second form. At second form is also Editbox which also take same value from settings like editbox in first form and have button which use to save editbox value in settings.

So now we have two forms with same controls, first form is used for reading from settings and second is for writing to settings. Now the question is: **How to automatic refresh (reload, update) editbox value from first form when same value is changed and saved in second form.**

Comment: How are you saving the data/setting? Is it in memory or to a file?

Comment: i don't know exactly i use Settings.Settings file in project to save, it's seems that those settings is saved in file!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be quite simple.

Write a static function in first form which can be accessed in the second form.

```
public class Form1 {
  public static void updateValue(string value) {
   editBox1.Text = value;
  }
}
```

and access the same function in Form2

```
public void updateForm1() {
  Form1.updateValue(editBox2.Text);
}
```

updateForm1() function should be called when the button in form 2 has been clicked.